# gcc 4.9 generic lambdas

Tags: gcc, lambda, c++14, gcc4.9

There said https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html, that generic lambdas supported since gcc 4.9.

But I tried following:

```
#include <iostream>

auto Identity = [](auto a) { return a; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << Identity(5) << std::endl;
}
```

And got error (-std=c++1y):

```
main.cpp:3:25: error: parameter declared 'auto'

 auto Identity = [](auto a) { return a; };
```

http://goo.gl/Omn8EA

Is it still not supported by gcc 4.9? Or I miss some parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you're using the pre-release gcc 4.9 experimental, change to the released gcc 4.9 and it compiles fine.
[Demo](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3a%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA+AKDIJm3SQElExsRsBPJAXiQG0BdACio0kBAJRIA3knzYYuMCIDcSAL6Ky4bEiIFw/UWQlkkJpDjgAuCxHTVUKeo2Zt+AVnEoH5qwjBwo6ipkQA=%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/opt/gcc-4.9.0/bin/g++%22,%22options%22%3a%22-std=c++1y%20-O0%22%7D%5D%7D)